# Symfony 2 + Doctrine | Entity must have all tags

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 2 and doctrine. I have 4 entities, CustomPage, Tag, CustomPageTag, Comment.

Every CustomPage can have many tags, and many comments.
I want to select a customPage (with all comments) which have some specific tags.

Example: I want to select the customPage with 'tag1' AND 'tag2'

I did this,

```
SELECT CUSTOMPAGE, TAG, CUSTOMPAGE_TAG, COMMENT
FROM CustomBundle:CustomPage CUSTOMPAGE
JOIN CUSTOMPAGE.comments COMMENT
JOIN CUSTOMPAGE.tags CUSTOMPAGE_TAG
JOIN CUSTOMPAGE_TAG.tag TAG
WHERE TAG.name IN ('tag1','tag2')
GROUP BY CUSTOMPAGE.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMPAGE_TAG.name) = 2
```

It works well, but the problem is that it return only one comment (I want it all).

Comment: Instead of joining did you try left joining three tables?

Comment: No, same ! It return the good result but without coments !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found it ! Doctrine allow using exsist ! so :

```
$qb->expr()->exists('SELECT b...')
```

Thank you guys for helping.

Answer (score 0):

you just get one comment because of using group by, instead use two join.

try this:

```
SELECT CUSTOMPAGE, TAG1, CUSTOMPAGE_TAG, COMMENT
FROM CustomBundle:CustomPage CUSTOMPAGE
JOIN CUSTOMPAGE.comments COMMENT
JOIN CUSTOMPAGE.tags CUSTOMPAGE_TAG
JOIN CUSTOMPAGE_TAG.tag TAG1
JOIN CUSTOMPAGE_TAG.tag TAG2
WHERE TAG1.name= 'tag1'
AND TAG2.name= 'tag2'
```